# How Can I Write A Function to split a video into its frames?

Tags: python, opencv

I was trying to write a function on Python that can split the frames of a video which I will later on use for deep learning purposes. It seems like there was no problem it created the files but when I open them, there is nothing inside.

Python, Visual Studio, OpenCV

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

video=cv2.VideoCapture('teknofest.mp4')
ret,frame=video.read()

def getFrames(vid):
    count=0
    for item in frame:
        cv2.imwrite(filename='frame%d.jpg' %count,img=item)
        print('WRITTEN FRAME:',count)
        count+=1
    return frame

getFrames(video)
```

.
I was hoping to get the frames but it just gave me 719 blank photos

Comment: video.read() must be in the loop (you have to read each frame).

Comment: and then you have to imwrite "frame" itself

Comment: thank you sir! I was confused about the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def getFrames():
    video = cv2.VideoCapture('teknofest.mp4')
    ok, frame = video.read()
    count = 0
    while ok:
        cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg".format(count), frame)
        print('WRITTEN FRAME:',count)
        count+=1
        ok, frame = video.read()
    video.release()

getFrames()
```

Comment: Made an edit because I forgot to fix the imwrite call.

Comment: You might want to change that frame%d to frame%04d or something, so the files get sorted properly